# bootstrap carousel within a column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have created a row with 3 columns (3-6-3) with a carousel in the middle column.

Everything seems to be working fine, however, I have unwanted space on either side of the middle column. See below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gGK4.jpg

I would like the left/right (columns containing the button groups) to be flush up against the carousel, if possible.

My code is below. And by the way, I am using the default (ie, unchanged/uneditted bootstrap.css)

```
<div class="container" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-block">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Online Payments</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Helpful Links</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Meetings</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

    <!--beginning of carousel-->

          <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200" alt="Chania">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200" alt="Chania">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200" alt="Flower">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200" alt="Flower">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>

<!--end of carousel-->  

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-block">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Legal Notices</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Phone Book</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Contact</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Thanks for any help you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bootstrap columns have a default 15px padding on either side so just add a class or id for the container wrapping the three columns and remove the padding like this:

HTML:

```
    <div class="container" id="carousel-contain" style="margin-bottom: 20px">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 left-col">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-block">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Online Payments</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Helpful Links</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Meetings</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">

    <!--beginning of carousel-->

          <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <!-- Indicators -->
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
          </ol>

          <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200" alt="Chania">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200" alt="Chania">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200" alt="Flower">
            </div>

            <div class="item">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/800x200" alt="Flower">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Left and right controls -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>
        </div>

<!--end of carousel-->  

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 right-col">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-block">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Legal Notices</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Phone Book</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Contact</button>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
#carousel-contain.col-md-3.left-col {
    padding-right:0px;
}
#carousel-contain.col-md-6 {
    padding:0px;
}
#carousel-contain.col-md-3.right-col {
    padding-left:0px;
}
```

Comment: You will noticed that I did not removed all the side paddings from the columns. This is to prevent the page alignment from breaking as removing all the side paddings will make the particular container will end up having a bigger width as compared to the other divs in your page.